# How to index columns with same name but different data in solr

Tags: solr, indexing

I have two table and both the tables have delete_status,but these columns have different data

**CODE:**(data-config.xml)

```
   <entity name="category_masters" query="SELECT                                 
   category_updated,delete_status,category_id,category_name FROM category_masters
   where category_id='${type_masters.category_id}'">
   category_id=${category_masters.category_id}"> 
   <field column="category_id" name="id"/>   
   <field column="category_name" name="category_name" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 **<field column="delete_status" name="delete_status" indexed="true" stored="true" />**
   <field column="category_updated" name="category_updated" indexed="true"      
   stored="true" />
   </entity>

   <entity name="type_masters" pk="type_id" query="SELECT     
   type_updated,delete_status as type_masters_delte,type_id,category_id,type_name FROM type_masters
   where type_id='${businessmasters.Business_Type}' "> 
   <field column="type_id" name="id"/>   
   <field column="category_id" name="category_id" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field column="type_name" name="type_name" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 **<field column="delete_status" name="delete_status" indexed="true" stored="true" />**
  <field column="type_updated" name="type_updated" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

How do i display data from both the columns,i tried aliasing the columns but it does not work.
And when i query i only see one delete_status column,even if i make it multivalued how do i differentiate which delete_status belongs to which table.
I want the data separately and cant make changes in the database.

Comment: could you post the code, how you have tried aliasing the columns? Is using the DIH an option?

Comment: iam trying to do it like its done in sql using "AS" so something like this 
delete_status as type_masters_delte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, i would use the [DIH](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler). In that case, you could define an join to merge both tables in data-config.xml.

Using that file supports aliases for Column names, like `table1.delete_status as type_masters_delete`

Comment: Hi Bndr thanks for the reply
But i dont know what do you mean by DIH,iam already doing a join.Iam new to solr please help

Comment: Sorry, I just notice, that this is still the `data-config.xml` in your listing, right? That worked for me with aliases, but I 1.) did not define the filed names/no field name mapping) and 2.) only used one `<entity>` element. Finlay the `data-config.xml` contains nothing more than connection-info and SQL statement.

Comment: i removed the field name and did the aliasing but it did not work.when i alias solr removes the field from the result

Comment: Is there a field in your `schema.xml` that matched to the alias name?

Comment: thank you Bndr,you solved the issue.I was stuck on this for a long time.I did not add the alias field in schema.xml file.The moment i did it worked.Thanks again